# Error in MongoDB script to define a new property in an array based on another property of the same document

Tags: mongodb

When trying to run the following script:

```
db.Invoices.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("65edac6d5ac9a2cf10156800")},
[
  { $set: { "Coupons.$.PaymentMethods": ["$Coupons.$.PaymentMethod"] } }
]);
```

The following error occurs:

```
Uncaught 
MongoServerError: Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.
```

[image: Script with error to update document]

I've already searched on several forums and in the official Mongo documentation, but I couldn't get it to work without using the cursor or $map.

Expected change to the document:
[image: Expected change to the document]

From: Brazil [Portuguese language]

This mentioned script was based on the following documentation:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#example-1--update-with-aggregation-pipeline-using-existing-fields

Comment: It would help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, preferably showing the full document before, and showing how you want it to look after the update.

Comment: You can't use `$[c]` to access element in sub document, must use real name in your document

Comment: I created a fictional situation to make it easier to understand:

I have invoices with an array of coupons, where each coupon has a defined payment method (nullable).
I need to create a new property in the coupons called "PaymentMethods" with an array of payment methods, where the value will be the payment method already defined in the array coupon itself. Next I will remove the old payment method property.

I will edit the topic with the dummy code with the desired document before and after the change.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the usage of the positional `$` operator. Check out [this official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to understand how `$` is used.

Answer (score 0):

After more research and attempts with the help of ChatGPT, I found a solution using $map and $cond to update the document array.

The script looked like this:

```
db.Invoices.updateMany(
   { "Coupons.PaymentMethods": {$exists: false} },
   [
     {
       $set: {
         "Coupons": {
           $map: {
             input: "$Coupons",
             as: "c",
             in: {
               $mergeObjects: [
                 "$$c",
                 {
                   PaymentMethods: {
                     $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["$$c.PaymentMethod", null] },
                       then: [],
                       else: ["$$c.PaymentMethod"]
                     }
                   }
                 }
               ]
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
     {
        // Remove the old property 'PaymentMethod'.
        $unset: "Coupons.PaymentMethod"
     }
   ]
);
```